# Java String Concatenation giving output as 2 equals 11 on concat 1+1+"equals"+1+1

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I wrote code in java and got output as `2 equals 11`.My code is

```
public class StringPrct 
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
String s= 1+1+" equals "+1 +1;
System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

Now the question is why i am not getting output as `2 equals 2`.

Comment: It's because you put spaces between the last two ones. Be careful, they do matter.

Comment: No on removing space also i am getting the same output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` operator has the [same precedence whether it's addition or concatenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18), and associates left-to-right. So:

```
1 + 1 + " equals " + 1 + 1
```

evaluates as

```
(((1 + 1) + " equals ") + 1) + 1
((2 + " equals ") + 1) + 1
("2 equals " + 1) + 1
"2 equals 1" + 1
"2 equals 11"
```

If you want to override this, you need to provide parentheses:

```
1 + 1 + " equals " + (1 + 1)
```

This becomes:

```
((1 + 1) + " equals ") + (1 + 1)
(2 + " equals ") + (1 + 1)
"2 equals " + (1 + 1)
"2 equals " + 2
"2 equals 2"
```

For clarity, you should probably add the parentheses to the first `1 + 1` as well, so that someone reading your code doesn't have to do the mental exercise of adding parentheses and evaluating down:

```
(1 + 1) + " equals " + (1 + 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

`1 + 1` is Integer(`2`)

`2 + " equals "` is casted to String(`2 equals`)

`"2 equals " + 1` is String(`2 equals 1`)

`"2 equals 1" + 1` is String(`2 equals 11`)

It should be `(1 + 1) + " equals " + (1 + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

adding a numeric to string gives a string. 1+1 is 2 as you are adding a int to int 2 + " equals " is string any thing afterwards will be just concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

After a string, Java is seeing other concatenated arguments as needing to have toString() called on them, apparently. You'll get correct output if you give Java a hint about operator order by putting your operations in parens:

```
String s= (1+1) +" equals "+ (1 +1);
```